# @Scripts.Render caused error after upgrade WebGrease.dll to 1.6.0 version and then deploy to azure web role

Tags: model-view-controller, webrole, webgrease

I uncounted a problem, after i upgraded the WebGrease.dll from 1.5.2 to 1.6.0, and deployed to azure web role, error occurred "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" , i have solved this problem by downgrade WebGrease.dll to previous version, but i still want to know why, may be next time we must upgrade to the newest version, can someone help me , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to occur when you use WebGrease 1.6.0 in conjunction with deploying to your cloud service w/ IntelliTrace enabled. Disabling IntelliTrace -or- downgrading WebGrease to 1.5.2 fixes the issue. As for why, I'd imagine you'll need to create an issue w/ WebGrease.

Comment: I have been getting a 'System.StackOverflowException' related to this bug. Can you imagine how hard it is to find good help via Google when you're searching for a solution to a StackOverflowException? It's not like that's the name of a popular site or anything :P This is the first answer that's been remotely helpful - Thanks